# How we can integrate payment gateway in to Phonegap mobile application?

Tags: cordova, payment-gateway

How to use the payment gateway in phonegap?
How much secure it is?
If we have any plugins so, after transaction is completed whether it reverts back to our phonegap app
Suggest me something.

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer to your question is a bit simpler. Just use a custom Stripe checkout form and have the response go to your server. And Voila. It should just work.

Comment: How to bring it back to the app, once the response goes to the server on success?